# Porqué no funciona mi webService?

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, webservice

Llevo varios días tratando de solucionar un problema desde el android studio conectándome a una bd remota por medio de php.

el archivo php me indica que la conexion ha sido correcta, "success" pero desde el android studio no me funciona, quisiera una colaboracion por favor!

éste es mi código de php

```
if (isset($_REQUEST)){

    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $passw = $_REQUEST['passw'];

    require_once 'connect.php';

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users_table WHERE email ='$email' AND passw = '$passw'";

    if ( mysqli_query($conn, $sql) ) {
        $result["success"] = "1";
        $result["message"] = "success";

        echo json_encode($result);
        mysqli_close($conn);

    } else {

        $result["success"] = "0";
        $result["message"] = "error";

        echo json_encode($result);
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
}
```

y este es el código en el android studio

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etEmail, etPassw;
    Button btnIntro, btnRetry;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        etEmail = findViewById(R.id.campoEmail);
        etPassw = findViewById(R.id.campoPassw);
        btnIntro = findViewById(R.id.btn_entrar);
        btnRetry = findViewById(R.id.btn_retry);

        btnRetry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent volver = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(volver);
            }
        });

        btnIntro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                login("http://aqui va mi dir ip/webservice/login.php");
            }
        });

    }

    private void login(String URL){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response.trim().equals("success")){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bienvenido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent epa = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Perfil.class);
                    startActivity(epa);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se pudo iniciar sesión", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error en la conexion: "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email",etEmail.getText().toString().trim());
                params.put("passw",etPassw.getText().toString().trim());
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema que veo es que desde el servidor respondes con un JSON, pero tu petición espera una cadena porque es del tipo `StringRequest`. Tienes que darle coherencia, o bien haciendo una `JSONObjectRequest` o bien respondiendo una cadena en el servidor. O sea, en vez de esto: `echo json_encode($result);` tendrías que responder esto: **`echo $result['message'];`**

Comment: El success solo indica que se pudo conectar correctamente. No quiere decir que    retorne datos. Deberias reemplazar `$_REQUEST` por `$_POST`. Saludos!

Comment: Si te fijas en tu sql, estas pasando el usuario y contraseña como string directamente. Es decir, no estas concatenando los valores correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Volley recibe tres tipos de peticiones:

- `StringRequest`
- `JSONObjectRequest`
- `JSONArrayRequest`

Según sea el tipo de petición, así tiene que ser la respuesta del servidor.

- `StringRequest`: una cadena cualquiera...
- `JSONObjectRequest`: un objeto JSON que sea válido. Los objetos JSON vienen encerrados entre los símbolos **`{  }`**:

  ```
  { ... datos organizados válidamente... }
  ```
- `JSONArrayRequest`: un array JSON, que es uno o varios objetos JSON dentro de un array, encerrado entre **`[ ]`**, algo así:

  ```
  [{ ... uno o más JSON válidos ...}, { ... objeto json ...}, { ... objeto json...} ]
  ```

Esas tres diferencias son fundamentales para escribir código coherente en cuanto a lo que pides al servidor, la respuesta de este y la forma en que lees esa respuesta.

En tu código precisamente se ve una **incoherencia: estás pidiendo una cadena:**

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
```

**pero desde el servidor respondes con un JSON:**

```
    echo json_encode($result);
```

Eso hace que no valide nunca aquí:

```
            if (response.trim().equals("success")){
```

porque en `response` hay un JSON, no una cadena. Lo puedes verificar poniendo algo como esto: `Log.d("WS",response);` y revisando el logcat. Verás que no hay sólo `success` sino todo lo que devuelves con `json_encode`.

Para hacer el código coherente puedes modificar el PHP así:

```
$email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : NULL;
$passw = !empty($_POST['passw']) ? $_POST['passw'] : NULL;

if ($email && $passw){

    require_once 'connect.php';

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users_table WHERE email ='$email' AND passw = '$passw'";

    if ( mysqli_query($conn, $sql) ) {
        $result["success"] = "1";
        $result["message"] = "success";

        //echo json_encode($result);
        //mysqli_close($conn);

    } else {

        $result["success"] = "0";
        $result["message"] = "error";

        //echo json_encode($result);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}else{

        $result["success"] = "0";
        $result["message"] = "error";

}
echo $result["message"];
```

OJO: he incluido algunas mejoras en tu PHP, haciéndolo más lógico. Y mando como respuesta la cadena del array que corresponde a `message` únicamente. No cambie el estilo que tenías de crear un array, porque puede que en un futuro necesites retornar más cosas, como un JSON con datos, en cuyo caso sí deberás usar `json_encode`, pero la petición debe ser del tipo `JSONObjectRequest` o `JSONArrayRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas parsear la repuesta que te llega del servidor:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        String mensaje = jsonObject.getString("message");
        if (mensaje.equals("success")){
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bienvenido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent epa = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Perfil.class);
                startActivity(epa)

        }else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error en la conexion: "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error1!!Por favor contacta al administrador"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```